The SonarScanner for MSBuild integration failed: SonarQube was unable to collect the required information about your projects in Azure Pipeline
I Have installed Sonarqube on my dev server.
I am preparing the pipeline in Azure Devops portal but after preparing the pipeline when i run that pipeline it is throwing the below error message?
##[error]03:01:36.038  The SonarScanner for MSBuild integration failed: SonarQube was unable to collect the required information about your projects.
I tried to implement the sonarqube for my Dev project using Azure Devops pipeline for code analysis but it is throwing error message.
